# Associate app with Package.StoreAssociation.xml

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-store

I deleted .vs folder from my projects to make them smaller.
When I load the project I can build everything. Except I lost association to the Store. I do have `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` file and `Projectname_StoreKey.pfx` file. Can I use them to tell the project about the association and restore association?

Comment: Can not repro. I open the solution again after deleting the .vs folder, the association is still there.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 15.6.6

Comment: @user3761570 How do you know the project lost association to the store? Besides, if you want the project smaller, you can delete the .bin and .obj file in a c# uwp project.

Comment: It prompts me to "Associate app with the Store".  Yes but .vs gets huge also.

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue in my side. If you want to upload your app to  store, you can [create an app package with the MakeAppx.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool) then upload it to store.